# Process hosting wpf application too long to shutdown

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a wpf application which after closing the main window, it takes around 20 seconds for the process to shutdown. What could be the possible reasons ?

Is it the Finalizer thread doing its work?

How can this be debugged to find the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have created thread which has *IsBackground* set to false therefore application keeps waiting until it terminates its action.